# Use reflection to automate EF5 Code First DbModelBuilder

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-5

I am trying to automate the DbModelBuilder object in OnModelCreating using reflection.

I have a number of classes that inherit from a base class: Enumeration
In the database i want to be able to set the Id's of these tables so in OnModelCreating I call

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>()
            .Property(sc => sc.SomeClassId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

I would like to automate this using reflection because if i forget to do this when the model is applied to the database i have to delete it and start again.

I know i could put an attribute on my class model but i don't want it there.

Here the code. For some reason it fails when i try to call my Generic Method. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
//Get all of my Models / Tables that I want to be able to specify a proimary key for.

var enumerationPropertyInfos = thisDbContext
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties();
    .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
        && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>)
        && p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First().BaseType == typeof(MyEnumerationBase));


foreach (PropertyInfo pi in enumerationPropertyInfos)
{
    //modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>()
    var config = modelBuilder.GetType()
        .GetMethod("Entity")
        .MakeGenericMethod(pi.PropertyType)
        .Invoke(modelBuilder, null);

    //Prepare .Property(...)
    var property = config.GetType().GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Property").First();

    var propertyExpression = typeof(Expression<>)
        .MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>)
        .MakeGenericType(pi.PropertyType, typeof(int)));

    //Prepare e => e.SomeClassId
    var paramEx = Expression.Parameter(pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First(), "e");
    var lambdaEx = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(paramEx, pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First().Name + "Id"), paramEx);

    //Execute .Property(e => e.SomeClassId)
    PrimitivePropertyConfiguration propertyResult = (PrimitivePropertyConfiguration)property
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Expression))
        .Invoke(config, new[] { lambdaEx });

    propertyResult.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your code, first is this line:

```cs
//modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>()
var config = modelBuilder.GetType()
    .GetMethod("Entity")
    .MakeGenericMethod(pi.PropertyType)
    .Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
```

As this is equivalent to:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<DbSet<SomeClass>>();
```

Change it to:

```cs
var config = modelBuilder.GetType()
    .GetMethod("Entity")
    .MakeGenericMethod(pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First())
    .Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
```

The second error is on this line:

```cs
var propertyResult = (PrimitivePropertyConfiguration)property
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Expression))
    .Invoke(config, new[] { lambdaEx });
```

You need to pass the type of `SomeClassId` as a generic parameter to `Property()` method but you are passing `typeof(Expression)` instead. Assuming SomeClassId is of type `int` change the line to:

```cs
var propertyResult = (PrimitivePropertyConfiguration)property
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int))
    .Invoke(config, new[] { lambdaEx });
```